# very strange stuff in rviz

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody,

I've been working for some time now on the assembly of a robotic arm from different stl parts. I don't have the original CAD model so I must do everything only with the stl files.

I don't know the distance between the joints either so I have to find it out by guessing-and-correcting, which is very annoying. However I noticed that sometimes rviz "guesses" the right position by himself, thus fitting the parts almost exactly. If I try to change the origin of the joint only a bit in the .urdf file it still stays at the same place!

This is of course wonderful when you have simple geometries (mother- father plugins for example) but it can be also very annoying with more complex parts, when rviz fits by itslef  parts in the WRONG position.

Why does rviz fit by itself parts anyway? Did anyone notice this behavior? It seems to me very strange. Does anyone know how to control/avoid this behavior?

Any clue or hint would be useful, please do tell me if you have the slightest guess

Thanks a lot

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36024/very-strange-stuff-in-rviz/) by [Lucian](https://answers.ros.org/users/1876/lucian/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2012-06-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-06-08**:
None of that is controlled by rviz. You can use the rviz TF Display to see what description your system is publishing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rviz does not guess any transformations between robot parts, but strictly shows what is defined in URDF robot models. If the transformation between parts is not properly published, all parts will be shown on top of each other at the current fixed coordinate system's origin, which might look like some sort of 'auto alignment' in some cases. Could this be what you're seeing?

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4